# how to know if user have denied the global location service or just the location service of the app?

Tags: ios, core-location

How to detect if user have denied the global location service or just the location service of the app ?

we can use `authorizationStatus` with `kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied` but this say:

> The that user explicitly denied the use of location services for this
>   app **OR** location services are currently disabled in Settings.

Comment: Why do you need to know?

Comment: because i need to show a popup to the user asking him to activate the location service. requestAlwaysAuthorization will not work if we already ask previously so we must redirect user to the settings, but need to know in with part of the settings we need to redirect the user.

Comment: In short, see `CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled`.

Comment: thanks yes it's was this, look easy to do :)